# C#: application integrating 2 SQL Server databases

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have to develop a C# application which should integrate 2 SQL Server-based applications.

I have developed some applications in C#, but these applications only manage one SQL Server database. I have no experience programming an integration. I have also developed SQL Server Management with Windows Services... But never a SQL Server Database Integration...

For example, when I create a Customer in Database A this Customer has to replicate in Database B. I have to replicate Customers, Contacts and Sales Orders.
The problem is that fields structure in Database A and B are not the same. For example, Customer table has more fields in Database B than Database A, and the fields that we could considerate as "common" has not the same format (for example, Customer ID is a varchar(20) in Database A and varchar(30) in Database B.

Which system should I use to integrate databases? I have read a lot about temporary tables, but I'm not sure for this to work...
Any suggestion??

Comment: Would be best if you reduced the question, would be good to expand on items like if the updates are real time or not, would ask for advice on a single point as well rather than a broad general statement

Answer (score 1):

> For example, when I create a Customer in Database A this Customer has to replicate in Database B. I have to replicate Customers, Contacts and Sales Orders.

You might want to rethink that. Manually replicated data is going to be a disaster because the two copies will eventually become out of sync and you'll never know if you're working with the correct data.

If you need to access data between multiple databases on the same server, you can specify the database name in your query as "RemoteServer.Database.Owner.Table" for as many tables or databases as you need.

If the DB is on a remote server, you can create a linked server and use that in your query.

If you actually need replication, I'd suggest using the native data replication features built into the server.